# Why don't the instances in the auto-scaling group get assigned public ip addresses unless it's a default vpc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-vpc, aws-codedeploy

I'm trying to migrate our deployment process over to aws code deploy (by following instructions here:https://pionect.nl/autoscaling-aws-laravel-codedeploy-opsworks-chef-automation/).

When I'm creating the auto-scaling group, I selected the same vpc as my other instances belong to. However when I do that, it says that it the ec2 instance will not be assigned a public ip. How come? My other instances have the same vpc id and are assigned an ip address just fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from AWS support:

The reason why you are seeing that notification is because it is in accordance to your launch configuration (staging-1-deploy) settings. During the creation of a launch configuration, the assignment of public IP addresses to EC2 instances defaults to `Only assign a public IP address to instances launched in the default VPC and subnet. (default)` [1]. To support automatic assignment of public IP addresses to your EC2 instances as they are launched, you will have to change the launch configuration settings. Since a launch configuration cannot be edited [2], you can create a new one by copying your current launch configuration. Follow the steps below to achieve this:

1. Go to your AWS console, select `Launch Configurations`, select `staging-1-codedeploy`
2. At the bottom of the details, click the grey `Copy Configuration` button on the right.
3. Click`Edit Details` link, then click `Advanced Details` on the resulting page.
4. Go to `IP Address Type` and select the second option, `Assign a public IP address to every instance.`
5. [optional] Change the name of the launch configuration if need be and
6. Save launch configuration

You can now proceed to use your new launch configuration for your auto-scaling group and all your EC2 instances will be assigned public IP addresses as desired.
I have attached a few screenshots to show some of the steps described above.

Comment: Where's the screenshots you mentioned?